# About pointers and strange error

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I'm doing pretty simple manipulations on pointers and I get an error. I have a function which gets a block, which is a continuous "block" in memory, which I want to fill in with the information below. `block` is `malloc`ed with size of (sizeof(int)+12+size). `username`'s length is 9 bytes (with the '\0').

```
typedef const char* const UserName;

static void changeAllFields(void **block, UserName username, int size){
            *((int*)(*block)) = size;
            (*block) += sizeof(int);
            *((char*)(*block)) = NULL;
            (*block) += 2;
            strcpy(*block, username);
            (*block) += 9;
            *((char*)(*block)) = NULL;
            (*block) += size;
            *((char*)(*block)) = NULL;
```

The error I get:

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

which points to: `*((char*)(*block)) = NULL;`

What is wrong ?

Comment: `username` is not a pointer, if you haven't `typedef`ed it. What type is `UserName`?

Comment: And it is poor form to hide pointer nature behind a typedef.

Comment: I did. 
          typedef const char* const UserName;

That is for readable purposes.

Comment: Try `*((char*)(*block)) = NULL;` --> `((char*)(*block)) = NULL;`.

Comment: ...unless you use [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) to make it clear: `pUserName`

Comment: `((char)(*block)) = NULL;` -> I see no such line in the code you presented.

Comment: You're also using non-standard void* pointer arithmetic. And there had better be sufficient memory referred to by `*block` for that copy and all the rest of this. You say this function "gets a block" - no, it *expects* a block to be pointed to by the pointer held in `block`. Honestly I don't see the need for the double-indirection on `block` in the first place.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the italicized-bold gremlins had their way with that line in the question.

Comment: Haris, I get: 

     lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: WhozCraig, I can pass just block which is void*, the problem is still exactly the same.

Comment: Try `*block = NULL;`

Comment: `*((int*)(*block)) = size;` breaks strict aliasing

Comment: can not perform pointer arithmetic on a void pointer as the compiler does not know how much to actually add to the 'block'  because it does not know what kind of thing is being pointed to.

Comment: strongly suggest 1) set the allocated memory to all '\0' (via memset()) before calling this function.  2) remove all the math being applied to the block pointer.  3) define a struct that defines all the fields in the allocated memory  4) modify the function signature to only have a single `*` on the first parameter 5) pay attention to memory alignment 6) remember that a 'int' could be 4 or 8 bytes depending on the underlying architecture so try `int32_t` rather than `int`.   After modifying the posted code into a complete function and compiling, there is a long list of problems, not just 1

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `block` is a `pointer to a pointer to void`, when you dereference it twice while casting it to `char*`, it would need a `char`.

---

If you want that to point to a `NUL` `char`, do

```
*((char*)(*block)) = '\0';
```

---

If you want to make it point to a `NULL` pointer, dereference it only once, like

```
*block = NULL;
```

Comment: I guess he doesn't want to set it to `NULL`, given that the next line increments its value.

Comment: @interjay, Yup, but i gave for information. I feel he wants to do `*((char*)(*block)) = '\0';`

Comment: Exactly, wow, I thought that is the same. thank you very much.

Comment: @Ilya.K., M a little curious, which one worked for you.

Comment: *((char*)(*block)) = '\0'; That one is the exactly what I meant.

Comment: I cant post another question, but it is the same code, as here, so I'll post it here: 
I have a simple function which gets pointer to continuous block of memory which is allocated by malloc. In the concrete "cell" which I'm trying to access by pointers arithmetic there is a char, which I want to return and then compare it as I wrote in the second code part.  

    static char getModOfBlock(void * block){
    return *((char*)(block-11));

}

Comment: if(!(getModOfBlock(*ptr_from_allocated) == 'A' || getModOfBlock(*ptr_from_allocated) == 'G' (userIsInTrust(memcache->users, user, username)) || (!strcmp(user, username)))){
    return MEMCACHE_PERMISSION_DENIED;
  }

The error that I get is: 

    called object is not a function or function pointer

What is wrong ?

Comment: Sorry about the mess, hope you'll understand it.

Comment: @Ilya.K., Its difficult to understand. Why can't you post another question.

Comment: There is a limit, only after 90 minutes as it said. I'll glad if you copy-past it into new post.
"You can only post once every 90 minutes."

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477061/using-a-simple-function-error

Here, the interface is the same. Maybe those guys there could help me too.

Comment: @Ilya.K., Hope they help, because I can't. Its all in russian. :p

Comment: I just missed || ) Stackoverflow rules )))

Comment: Yes, it is. I just didn't noticed that missing symbol.

Comment: @Ilya.K., Good. Have a happy coding session. Bye. :)

Comment: There is another interesting and technical point down below. Maybe you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is a pointer value, but you're writing it into `*((char*)(*block))` which has type `char`. If you actually want to write a `char` with a value of zero, it should be:

```
*(char*)(*block) = 0;
```

Note also that arithmetic operations on a `void*` as you do in `(*block) += 2;` are illegal, although some compilers may support them as an extension.

Comment: Yes, now I'm trying to compile it on Visual Studio 2015 and it writes to me that the expression must be a pointer to a full type object.

And also that void* size unknown. The GCC compiler do fine with evaluating void*, because sizeof(void*) defined as same as sizeof(char) = 1 byte. But how do I repair it, any suggestion ?

I've tried ((*char)block) += sizeof(int);

But it yell's at me "needed an expression" and ")" is missed, and as you can see, as I want it to work, there isn't.

Comment: Ok, figure it out, just make char ***ptr = block or *block (if it **void**) and then do all operations on it.

Comment: regarding this statement: `The GCC compiler do fine with evaluating void*, because sizeof(void*) defined as same as sizeof(char) = 1 byte.`.  this is not true.   a pointer is always the same size, regardless of what type and/or what it is pointing toward.   Every compiler understands the size of a `void*`.   What it will not know is the size of the object being pointed to by that `void*`